# What JavaScript technique is being used in react to inject properties into its corresponding class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What JavaScript technique is being used so that a class component can accept the passed in properties in `this` context.

In the below code I am passing "test" property to its Home class component. In Home class component I can accept the passed in "test" property in the `this` context. I am curious to know what JavaScript technique is being used behind the scene to achieve this (making passed in properties available to class component).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Home from './Home'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Home test='test prop' />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

## Home Class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      conter:0
    }

    console.log("Constructor",this.props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("Mount Method",this.props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Render",this.props);   
    return (
      <div>
        Hello        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Also why the properties are undefined in Constructor method. Or , why the properties are defined in `ComponentWillMount` and `Render` method in the above code?. I mean why the `console.log()` inside constructor method is showing `undefined` and other `console.log` inside `componentWillMount()` and `render()` are showing correct passed in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your constructor

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      console.log(this.props)
    }
```

try it out, you should get output from this.props

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your Home class you get your result.

thanks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      conter:0
    }

    console.log("Constructor",this.props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("Mount Method",this.props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Render",this.props);   
    return (
      <div>
        Hello        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor has some problems, the correct version is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      conter:0
    }

    console.log("Constructor",this.props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("Mount Method",this.props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Render",this.props);   
    return (
      <div>
        Hello        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, as already mentioned:

"When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call `super(props)` before any other statement"
(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

The "JavaScript technique" used specially in React is JSX:
"JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the `React.createElement(...)`"
(https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Your code with `ReactDOM.render(<Home ...>, ...)` ist "translated" to:
`React.createElement(Home, { test: 'test prop' }, ...)`
That's how React "knows" how to instantiate the class and set the props.

If you want to look at it in detail, check out the code at: 
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js

Comment: I was checking the ReactElement.js file but couldn’t find the instantiation of the class. Can you tell me which line is responsible for this.